# run timer automatically for first and second time

Tags: iphone, ios4, timer, ios-simulator, nstimer

I am new to iPhone,
What I want is that my timer call a function every second but for the very first time it must call the function at 2 second.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a variable

```
BOOL isNotFirstTime;
```

And in the function that gets triggered after each 4 secs add the following code at the starting

```
-(void)AfterOneSecondsFuction
 {
   if(!isNotFirstTime)
   {
    isNotFirstTime=YES;
    return;
   }
  //YOUR CODE HERE...
 }
```

This is how you give a call to the function

```
 NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(AfterOneSecondsFuction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for immediate response @iCoder

Answer (score 0):

First schedule a timer and have a `BOOL` variable say `isFirstTime` set as `YES`;

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(doSomething) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and in

```
- (void)doSomething
{
if(isFirstTime)
{
isFirstTime = NO;
return;
}
// Do something


}
```